# Django, bundle together count queries?

Tags: django, optimization, django-queryset

Lets say I have the relation

```
class Person(models.Model):
      is_asian  = models.BooleanField()
      is_male   = models.BooleanField()
      is_gay    = models.BooleanField()
      last_name = models.ForeignKey('FamilyName')
      is_happy  = models.BooleanField()

class FamilyName(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
```

Currently, when I want to get a bunch of statistics about my population I do

```
have_x_many_males   = Person.objects.filter(is_male=True).count()
have_x_many_gays    = Person.objects.filter(is_gay=True).count()
have_x_many_roberts = Person.objects.filter(last_name_id='robert').count()
...
```

However this is incredibly inefficient if the number of statistics I have grows

Is there a way to bundle the queries altogether and execute them at once and get back a list or something ?

```
>>> main_query = [query_1, query_2, query_3]
>>> main_query.execute()
{'have_x_many_males':5, ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)

```
from django.db import models

aggregates = {
    'have_x_many_males': models.Sum(models.Case(models.When(is_male=True, then=1), output_field = models.IntegerField())),
    'have_x_many_roberts': models.Sum(models.Case(models.When(last_name_id='robert', then=1), output_field = models.IntegerField())),
}

queryset = Person.objects.all().annotate(**aggregates)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, but what If I dont want the `Person` objects themselves, but only the annotations? Would I just do a `values()` after the `annotate()` ?

Comment: @Alan Yeah it should work, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Answer (score -1):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    is_asian  = models.BooleanField()
    is_male   = models.BooleanField()
    is_gay    = models.BooleanField()
    last_name = models.ForeignKey('FamilyName')
    is_happy  = models.BooleanField()

    def get_count(self):
        return{
            'have_x_many_males': Person.objects.filter(is_male=True).count()
            'have_x_many_gays': Person.objects.filter(is_gay=True).count()
            'have_x_many_robertss': Person.objects.filter(last_name_id='robert').count()
        }
```

Then do `p = Person.objects.all().get_count()`

Comment: I mean bundle them into the same connection for optimization reasons. Not wrap them in some method

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the *same connection*.

Comment: These are simple queries, they take very little time for the DB to handle. But to connect to the DB is expensive, and django has to do it X many times. I want to bundle all counts into 1 single giant query and get 1 single giant request back to avoid multiple hits